# Unable to delete a properties file

Tags: java

I have to delete a property file from the path specified. I used the following code:

```
File f1 = new File("C:\\Equinox\\UIDesign\\root\\root.properties"); 
boolean success=f1.delete();
```

It returns false.

But a text file instead of property file is succesfully deleted.

Comment: Have you tried deleting it "by hand", see if you have the proper rights?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why `File.delete()` can fail:

- It's a directory and not empty
- You don't have the OS permission to delete the file
- The file is still opened somewhere

The last one could be your own fault, if you've opened a FileInput/OutputStream for that file and forgot to close it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Michael, his answer makes a lot of sense. Just a comment on your code, you should be doing the following to catch all possible errors and notify the user accordingly:

```
try{
 File f1 = new File("C:\\Equinox\\UIDesign\\root\\root.properties"); 
 boolean success=f1.delete();
 if(!success){
    // Notify user that the file 
 }
catch(SecurityException ex){
 // No sufficient rights to do this operation
}
```